# Buenos dias tengo un problema al hacer un update en la fecha

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
 var Actualizacion = db.Libro.Where(x => x.Sticker == txtSticker.Text).ToList();
  l.IdSector += 5;
            l.FechaCarga += DateTime.Now();
```

Me dice que no se puede usar como metodo el miembro DateTime.Now no invocable

Answer (score 1):

Now es una properidad del clase DateTime, no es un metodo.  Quiere

```
DateTime.Now
```